# Why would java.awt.image.BufferedImage#getType return different value Mac & CENTOS

Tags: java, image-manipulation, awt

I have a question about the [BufferedImage#getType](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#getType%28%29) method. When referencing a PNG image from the file system, the following code will print **5** in my Mac and **0** in a CENTOS box with this JVM:

java version "1.6.0_03"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_03-b05)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 1.6.0_03-b05, mixed mode)

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.io.*;

public class ImageTypeTest {

   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
      BufferedImage sourceImage = ImageIO.read(new File("/path/to/png.png"));
      System.out.println(sourceImage.getType());
   }

}
```

Can anyone please shed some light as to what might be causing this difference so that I can work around it? The code returns the same values for other image types, say GIF images.

Thank you

Comment: this is totally normal.  What do you mean by *"working around it"*?  You can instantiate your own BufferedImage with the exact type you want and copy the image you read in that BufferedImage.  AFAIK you cannot force ImageIO.read to create directly the BufferedImage type you want.  Also note that forcing your own BufferedImage type will likely result in sub-optimal performances when manipulation said image on the various platforms you're targetting.

Comment: Hello Webinator, I understand that is normal; the question is, what is the cause? why do I get different image types for the same image in the different operating systems? That's what I don't understand, why would they be different if it's the very same image file? Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for the difference is that the Java implementations in OS X and CENTOS use different underlying libraries to parse the PNG image - which they're allowed to, as there is nothing in ImageIO's contract requiring it to produce a particular image type.

If you want to have a consistent (and fast to draw) image, the best thing to do is to use the following code to convert the image into the colour space being used by the display system:

```
GraphicsConfiguration config = new JFrame().getGraphicsConfiguration();
// Or better, use your main GUI component instead of new JFrame()
BufferedImage fixedImg = config.createCompatibleImage(img.getWidth(), img.getHeight(), Transparency.TRANSLUCENT);
Graphics2D fig = fixedImg.createGraphics();
fig.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
fig.dispose();
fixedImg.flush();
```

Comment: Hey Zarkonnnen. I really appreciate your answer. Because my code will execute in a 'headless' server environment, I ended up using the GraphicsConfiguration of another image read through ImageIO.read() like this: sourceImage.createGraphics().getDeviceConfiguration(); Thanks again